# Recovering deleted TrueCrypt volume corrupted it

Tags: truecrypt

I recently accidentically deleted a TrueCrypt volume. I was able to recover it using [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva), but now it seems the volume has been corrupted. Mounting it first fails with the message "Incorrect password or not a Truecrypt volume" and I'm possitive I'm using the correct password.

I then tried mounting while using the "Use local headers if available" option, and then it worked. But to my disapointment I then discovered the mounted drive was empty and I was prompted to format it before I could use it. Obviously, there's still something wrong with the volume file.

ANY suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: It would surprise me if you would be able to recover the volume. Even a part of it. In order to successfully mount the volume and access its contents, 100% of the volume must be recovered. If even one tiny sector had been overwritten during the time it was deleted, chances are the volume is fubar.

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/259424/recovering-corrupt-truecrypt-disk?rq=1